# Cone from direction vector

Tags: math, opengl, glsl, raycasting

I have a normalized direction vector (from a 3d position to a light position) and I would like this vector to be rotated by some angle so I can create a "cone".

Id like to simulate cone tracing by using the direction vector as the center of the cone and create an X number of samples to create more rays to sample from.

What I would like to know is basically the math behind:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/BlueprintAPI/Math/Random/RandomUnitVectorinCone/index.html

Which seems to do exactly what Im looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make arbitrary vector P, perpendicular to your direction vector D.
You can choose component with max magnitude, exchange it with middle-magnitude component, negate it, and make min magnitude component zero.

For example, if z- component is maximal and y-component is minimal, you may make such P:

```
 D = (dx, dy, dz)
 p = (-dz, 0, dx)
 P = Normalize(p)   //unit vector
```

2) Make vector Q perpendicular both D and P through vector product:

```
  Q = D x P    //unit vector
```

3) Generate [random point in the PQ plane disk](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)

```
  RMax = Tan(Phi)  //where Phi is cone angle

  Theta = Random(0..2*Pi)

  r = RMax * Sqrt(Random(0..1))   

  V = r * (P * Cos(Theta) + Q * Sin(Theta))
```

4) Normalize vector V

Note that distribution of vectors is slightly non-uniform on the sphere segment.(it is uniform on the plane disk). There are methods to generate [uniform distribution on the sphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) but some work needed to apply them to segment (my first attempt before edit was wrong).

**Edit:** Modification to make sphere-uniform distribution (not checked thoroughly)

```
 RMax = Tan(Phi)  //where Phi is cone angle
 Theta = Random(0..2*Pi)
 u  = Random(Cos(Phi)..1)
 r = RMax * Sqrt(1 - u^2)   
 V = r * (P * Cos(Theta) + Q * Sin(Theta))
```