# Create a triangle around a point, perpendicular to a normal

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I'd like get the points of a triangle around a point where the face would point in the direction of a specified normal. I'll be using THREE.js to add them to a BufferGeometry.

Very crude drawing:

[image: Please forgive this very crude drawing]

Here's the code I have so far:

```
//The XYZ location of a point:
var x = model.points[i*3];
var y = model.points[i*3+1];
var z = model.points[i*3+2];


//The normal vector direction:
var nx = model.normals[i*3];
var ny = model.normals[i*3+1];
var nz = model.normals[i*3+2];
```

How can I pick 3 more points around this point that are all perpendicular to the normal and the same distance from the point / each other?

THANKS!

Comment: Clarification: Is `v3` in your picture supposed to be pointing out of the page?

Comment: If so, there are not enough constraints here to determine unique values for for the three vertices of such a triangle. There are infinitely many choices.

Comment: yeah, I see what you mean but it doesn't matter what angle the triangle is. that's kind of why i'm finding it confusing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - yes.

Comment: Since you don't care, you will have to pick an arbitrary starting point. From there if you want to make an equilateral triangle the rest is pretty trivial.

Comment: A point can't be perpendicular. Only a line can be.

Comment: @AmrBerag Technically *a* line can't be perpendicular, either, since perpendicularity is a relation between *two* objects. I think the idea is that the plane which contains the triangle is perpendicular to the normal vector.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice A line can indeed be perpendicular to a a line or a plane. A point can not.

Answer (score 1):

1) Take cross product of the normal with an arbitrary non-parallel vector. This will get you a vector perpendicular to the normal vector.

1.5) Normalize and scale the perpendicular vector to desired size. The length of this vector will be the distance from the triangle's centroid to each of its vertices.

2) Rotate the perpendicular vector by 2PI/3 and 4PI/3 around the normal vector.

3) Add the 3 vectors to the center point.

Comment: can the arbitrary vector be anything at all?

Comment: @JonathanPlackett Yes, that's what "arbitrary" means

Comment: Note, it must be non-parallel to the normal vector, otherwise the cross product will be a zero vector.

Comment: I've got this working, but because I'm choosing an arbitrary point, the triangle I end up with varies in size. Is there a way to make them consistent?

Comment: Sure, normalize and scale your vector in step 1.5.

Comment: [The first part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404576/cone-from-direction-vector/39406558#39406558) shows an approach to generate perpendicular vector

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are infinitely many triangles that fit your criteria, even if we limit to only equilateral triangles. This is because there is an entire plane which is perpendicular to the given vector `<nx, ny, nz>` through the given point `(x, y, z)`. [Read here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429131/find-an-equation-of-the-plane-perpendicular-to-vector-v-and-passing-through-the) to see how to derive the equation for that plane. From there, you will need to pick a point on the plane. Then you can calculate the other two points by rotating around the given point at `(x, y, z)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the plane parallel to the normal and containing the point (there is only one)  and then pick any point in this plane with the specified distance and rotate it two times by 120 degree around the centeral point.